# what is the ideal buttons size for both ios and andriod

Tags: usability, touch-screen

I have designed a mobile application, but I want to know what is the best size for the buttons for both (ios and andriod) so that I do not encounter problems with the operating system and user experience.

Answer (score 0):

You have every information on google:

---

In this [article](https://uxplanet.org/7-rules-for-mobile-ui-button-design-e9cf2ea54556) it's 7 principles about button design.

1. Stick to the core UI design principles
2. Use color to make UI buttons look actionable
3. Help users prioritize tasks by removing friction on-screen
4. Reward users with visual feedback
5. Location: place buttons where users can find them in the UI
6. Be consistent with defining design trends as well as your own UI design
7. Make sure that your button does what it says it does with a label

---

> In the Human Interface Guidelines, Apple recommends a minimum target
>   size of 44 pixels (px) wide 44 pixels tall.

---

> When ‘tap’ is the primary input method for your mobile app, Android’s
>   Material Design principles recommend that touch targets should be at
>   least 48 x 48dp, with at least 8dp (or more) between them. This is to
>   ensure balanced information density and usability.

---

Edit:

[image]

Comment: To note: minimum target size doesn't mean minimum button size, though I'd recommend them to be equal. Target size is the area that captures the touch on tap.

Comment: for the sake of accuracy, I agree. Always button ∈ target size. So if minimum target is 48pd - so minimal button too.